# Should I pluralize the object of a plural subject?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Examples:

> We can help ensure future shoppers complete their purchase.

vs

> We can help ensure future shoppers complete their purchases.

Another:

> The new law mandates city bikers wear a helmet.

vs.

> The new law mandates city bikers wear helmets.

I believe I was taught that the pluralization of the subject *must* match the pluralization of the object.  So, *"mandates city bikers wear a helmet"* would be incorrect, since it would technically imply those bikers were collectively wearing a single helmet. If we really wanted to use *"a helmet"*, we could say *"The new law mandates every city biker wear a helmet"*, since *every* singularizes *biker*.

But, common usage would imply both are correct.  What's the proper form here?

Comment: A shopper might make one or more purchases, but a biker will only wear one helmet. So the first pair of examples about shoppers can be either, but the second about bikers might be arguable.

Comment: Why don't you regard the option "The new law mandates city bikers to wear their helmets"/"The new law mandates that city bikers wear their helmets"?

Comment: [Related post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/99607/subject-object-agreement)